# site looks good on "open with Live Server" (vs code) but no CSS loading in the browser

Tags: html, css, server, visual-studio-code, live

My website looks fine when viewed with "Open with Live Server" on VS Code but looks terrible in the browser (no CSS is loading). What is going on?

I have already:

1) cleared my cache

2) checked all the links to my CSS

3) checked my divs and classes and all that

IMPORTANT: I'm using Skeleton CSS cdn AND linking to my own small bit of custom css (style.css).

For the love of God please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It could be helpful if you can mention the browser that you've tried and even try different browsers -if possible, just to see  if the behaviour is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you're loading mixed content, (Non SSL content for SSL page)

This article explains the mixed content problem.

> Mixed content occurs when initial HTML is loaded over a secure HTTPS connection, but other resources (such as images, videos, stylesheets, scripts) are loaded over an insecure HTTP connection. This is called mixed content because both HTTP and HTTPS content are being loaded to display the same page, and the initial request was secure over HTTPS. Modern browsers display warnings about this type of content to indicate to the user that this page contains insecure resources.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content

Answer (score 0):

I have got a same mistake. I design my website using chrome and I reduced the screen size , so when I run through vs code live server the site looks fine but the screen size is 75% but when I open through the folder it looks bad  . Text and images are scrambled, but the screen size is 100% ( actual size ). So just configure the screen size before you make site.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31051509)